# Law of total probability and Bayes Rule

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, and a region $E$ in the image of $X$. I want to evaluate

$$
P(X \in E | Y = y) \\
= \frac{ P(X \in E \cap Y = y) }{ P(Y=y) } \\
= \frac{ P( Y = y  | X \in E  ) P(X \in E) }{ P(Y=y) } \\
$$
So far so good. Now to go the next step, I need to sum over values of X. Are the following three all equivalent? Are they all true?:
$$
=A = \frac{ \int_{Im X} P( Y = y  | X \in E  ) P(X \in E | X = x) P(X = x) dx }{ P(Y=y) } \\
$$
or 
$$
=B = \frac{ \int_{Im X} P( Y = y  | X \in E, X = x   ) P(X \in E | X = x) P(X = x) dx }{ P(Y=y) } \\
$$

or 
$$
=C = \frac{ \int_{Im X} P( Y = y  |  X = x   ) P(X \in E | X = x) P(X = x) dx }{ P(Y=y) } \\
$$

How can I tell which of these are equivalent, either mathematically or by visualization/intuition?

Comment: Top three are equivalent if $\mathbb{P}(y=0) >0$.

Comment: @ChargeShivers Yes my question is about the bottom three, labeled A,B,C.